# No button events in iphone 5 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

When I test my app running in the iPhone 6 simulator everything works as expected. If I however test it in the iPhone 5 or iPhone 5.1 simulators, I can't seem to get button events fired. Im using Xcode 4.5.2, not using storyboards and I have made tests with simple buttons with actions like:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"YEES");
}
```

And the actions is connected using drag and drop in the interface builder. I just can't seem to get it fired.. Do you have any idea about what could be the problem?

**Update Jan 18:**

If I do a "normal" click on a button in the iPhone 5/5.1 simulator nothing happens. If I do a bit "slow" click on a button the button will be "pressed"/selected. If I do a "really slow" click, like holding the button down for 3 seconds I get the button click event! How is this possible??

Comment: Is `userInteractionEnabled` on the button?

Comment: userInteractionEnabled is enabled, yes.

Comment: with which event you are connecting your IBAction. it should be touchupinside.

Comment: i'm have the same issue, if you find solution - write it plz. In ios6 all buttons pressed as suggested, but on ios5 simulator them fire event only after very-very long click...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my case - i added UITapGestureRecognizer to the container UIView, and it intercepts events before UIButtons, and need some time to fail before buttons can handle tap... But it strange that in iOS 6 all works fine

To avoid this we can simply call:

```
[tapRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I really suspect this could be the issue of view overlapping.
Please color your views that you are using on the view controllers and check whether any of your view is overlapping your button or not

Comment: After coloring my different views it seems like there is no overlapping views. However check my update in the question - I think I was able to narrow the problem a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an iPhone 5s simulator. Through trial and error I realized that the button's height in the simulator was 0 or otherwise a small number... The first clue to that was that when I changed its background color - the background did not show in the simulator (on larger simulators, like 6 or 6 plus, it showed as a thin line instead of full height). Then when I added a height constraint, it started accepting click events.  That helped me identify the issue, but it was not the solution I was looking for. Initially I laid the button out without size constraints, so it's actual size should have been determined by it's intrinsic size. So instead of the height constraint, I changed the vertical compression resistance of the button to "required". That fixed the issue.